# Выбор CMS для интернет-магазина с возможностью интеграции с 1С?

Tags: веб-программирование, cms, 1с, интернет-магазин, интеграция

Доброе время суток. Встал перед выбором CMS для интернет-магазина. Требуется интеграция с 1С. Ранее никогда таким безобразием не занимался (интеграцией с 1С), поэтому нахожусь в полной прострации. Слышал про Bitrix, но бюджет не позволяет. Ищу совета и помощи.

Comment: к сожалению, на этом сайте навряд ли вы найдёте подобные советы; вопросы, разжигающие холивары, тут не приветствуются

Comment: Посоветуйте, где еще можно задать подобный вопрос? Очень уж нужна информация

Comment: @DimDim попробуйте пойти с этим на http://forum.mista.ru, но всё-таки у вас вопрос слишком общий, нужны детали - хотя бы какая конфигурация.

Comment: Благодарю всех за советы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз **Bitrix** не годится, попробуй посмотреть в сторону бесплатного **OpenCart** (http://www.opencart.com), на него можно установить модуль для работы с **1C** (https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=170256)

Comment: Бесплатный WordPress тоже имеет плагин магазина WooCommerce, а к нему есть интеграция с 1С

Comment: @KAGGDesign, не спорю, я предложил как вариант CMS, которая полностью ориентирована на e-commerce, в отличии от wordpress

Comment: Да и я не спорю, дополнил ваш ответ.

Comment: Благодарю всех за советы)